# Dropdown default value Powerapps

Tags: dropdown

need to set dropdown down default value to a sharepoint list item that is not top of the list.

Using formula:
LookUp(Choices(DIS_Projects_Master_Data.Project), Value= "Please select")

this is giving me an error.
could anyone help.

Thanks

Comment: What is the error message? Where are you adding this formula (for which property)?

Comment: I am adding it to the dropdown default property

Comment: What is the error message when you use above formula. Check this if it helps: https://powerusers.microsoft.com/t5/Building-Power-Apps/How-to-set-a-pre-populated-default-value-of-a-Dropdown-in/td-p/19800

Comment: I have two numbers in different box, if one is bigger than the other, I want a third box to display ON/ Off track

Comment: I think you commented on wrong post. Are you trying to comment on another question of yours at: https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/304071/comparing-two-textinputs

Comment: apologies, wrong post :)