# Comparing two text inputs values in Power Apps

Tags: sharepoint-online, powerapp, powerapps-forms, powerapps-canvas, formula

I want to compare to text input values. The result shows as "on track" or "off track".

Formula:

```
If(Value(TextInput1_1.Text)> Value(TextInput1.Text),  "ON TRACK", If(Value(TextInput1_1.Text)< Value(TextInput1.Text), "OFFTRACK"))
```

Not getting any output. Any ideas?

Comment: Where do you adding this formula? Inside "Text" property of label control or somewhere else? Are the values inside text inputs are of type number?

Comment: I want to add value inside TextInput as text

Comment: Try solution given in my answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set `Default` property of third text input to:

```
If(
    Value(TextInput1_1.Text) > Value(TextInput1.Text),
    "ON TRACK",
    Value(TextInput1_1.Text) < Value(TextInput1.Text),
    "OFF TRACK"
)
```

**Documentation**: [If function in Power Apps](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-platform/power-fx/reference/function-if)